# Issue with XML to SQL query hanging

Tags: sql, xml

I'm converting an XML document into a SQLExpress database table. The XML has 42,000 records. When I run the query, it just continues to execute and never finishes. It ran for 48 hours last and didn't finish. I ended the query and ran a SELECT * from the table and it was blank.

Here is my query:

```
Use DATABASE
Go

INSERT INTO TABLE(CitizenName, LicenseNo, Address, CityStateZip, IssueDate, ExpireDate, Type, Restriction, MayOperate, Sex, DOB, Height, Weight, Hair, Eyes, Remarks, NewRenewal)
SELECT
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('NAMELASTFIRSTMI').value('.', 'VARCHAR(150)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('LICENSE_x0020_NO').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('ADDRESS_x0020_VILLAGE').value('.', 'VARCHAR(200)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('CITY_x0020_STATE_x0020_ZIP').value('.', 'VARCHAR(200)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('ISSUEDATE').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('EXPIREDATE').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('TYPE').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('RESTRICTION').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('MAYOPERATE').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('SEX').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('DOB').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('HEIGHT').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('WEIGHT').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('HAIR').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('EYES').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('REMARKS').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)'),
   MY_XML.BMVDLLIST.query('NEWRENEW').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')

FROM (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\USER\Desktop\BMVDLLIST.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
      CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('dataroot/BMVDLLIST') AS MY_XML (BMVDLLIST);
```

No errors, just continues to execute.

Comment: Have you tried with a small piece of data?

Comment: Are you suggesting I piecemeal the XML into the table? Do you think the issue is the size it is parsing?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jamie Drq, who commented, I split my xml up. I passed the first 5000 records through this morning and it successfully parsed and added to the table after 5 and half hours. So I’ll just do this slow process of piecemealing it.

Thanks!